# Why would C# linq to sql return the same exact record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

So I have this Entity Framework query in which the `SELECT` statement  which i can copy and run in sql server `ctx.MainOrders` returns 2 very different records.

However when i run this LINQ query with  `.AsEnumerable()` and `.Select(z => new MainOrder()`  i'm getting the EXACT SAME record twice!   :/

This class is a POCO

```
 public class MainOrder
```

Here is my query

```
public List<MainOrder> GetMainOrder(string hashString)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new ClearContext())
            {
                    var query = ctx.MainOrders
                       .Where(z => z.MainId == queryHashMain)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(z => new MainOrder()
                       {
                           Email = z.Email,
                           AuthorizationFirstName = z.AuthorizationFirstName,
                           AuthorizationLastName = z.AuthorizationLastName,
                           Btn = z.Btn,
                           AccountNumber = z.AccountNumber,
                           UtilityTypeName = z.UtilityTypeName
                       }).ToList();
                    return query;



                return new List<MainOrder>();

            }
        }
```

Comment: `query[0].UtilityTypeName`  and `query[1].UtilityTypeName`  BOTH have value "Electric"   ( 1 should be Gas )

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `query[].utilityTypeName`?

Comment: @NetMage  watch window in visual studio

Comment: That doesn't let you *assign* a value.

Comment: @NetMage  --  I removed 40 properties  ... as it is not needed to show all of the those,  i should add that one back in to question though

Comment: @NetMage  - ok,  showing it now

Comment: If you are getting the same record twice then it is in the database twice.  To prevent a record from occuring twice the field in the database must be set to a primary key.  The ssql server will not allow two entries with the same primary key.  When you do not have a primary key then the sql server will insert multiple record.

Comment: interesting.  the ctx.Mainorders query will show 2 records in sql server as it is a View in which MainId is the primary key,   [Key] is above the property for it in the poco,   but the view consist of join where the main table does have 1 record and it is joined to orderdetail table in which mainid is in that table twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you mention a VIEW , that is the issue I bet.

> the ctx.Mainorders query will show 2 records in sql server as it is a View in which MainId

Add in method `AsNoTracking`  for view

```
var query = ctx.MainOrders.AsNoTracking()
```